# Update Kotlin Flow on value change

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using this code to get my user from the Firebase Realtime Database in my Android app:

```
    private var _user = getUser(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid ?: "NULL")
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), null)
```

The idea is that I can get flow updates about the user from the database, and when the user isn't logged in, (`firebaseAuth.currentUser == null`) the database reference is `NULL` and so the `_user` would be `null`.

But when I'm trying to log in, for example, I'm updating `firebaseAuth.currentUser` but the `getUser` function isn't recalled so the app still thinks `_user` is null.

I have 2 Questions:

- How can update the value of `_user` (or recall `getUser`) as soon
  as I login (when `firebaseAuth.currentUser` changes?)?
- And if that's not possible, how can I manually recall `getUser` and set the value of `_user`?

Here is my `getUser` function (if that help):

```
    private fun getUser(userId: String): Flow<User?> {
    return callbackFlow {
        val userRef = databaseReference.child("Users/$userId")
        val listener = userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue<User>()
                trySend(user)
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Cancel the flow on error
                cancel()
            }
        })
        // Return the listener to be used to cancel the flow
        awaitClose {
            userRef.removeEventListener(listener)
            channel.close()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have to use a [FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) which contains a method called [onAuthStateChanged(auth: FirebaseAuth)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)) which is triggered each time the auth state changes.

Now when it comes to Kotlin, it's best to use a [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html). In code it should look like this:

```
fun getAuthState(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
    val authStateListener = AuthStateListener { auth ->
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), auth.currentUser == null)
```

Comment: sorry for being beginner with kotlin flows, but how can I observe this to update ``_user`` when auth state change?

Comment: You should call such a function from within a ViewModel class, and then call collectAsState() inside the view and check the value.  Check this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) as it will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: I'm sorry, but i see that I can observe the changes from my activity, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to get. How can I call ``getUser`` on change of the state from my viewmodel?

Comment: To know when the auth state is changed, as I mentioned in my answer, you should use the FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener. If you don't care about architecture, then you can use that in the ViewModel.

Comment: at the end, your answer did helped with FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener, but I ended up with something like this:
Firebase.auth.addAuthStateListener {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                repo.getUserFromDb()
                    .collect { user ->
                        _state. Update { state ->
                            state. Copy(
                                user = user,
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
with collect

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for user object be available upon authentication

```
private val currentUser = callbackFlow {
        if (firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid != null) {
            trySend(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!)
            awaitClose {

            }
            return@callbackFlow
        }
        val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            val user = it.currentUser ?: return@AuthStateListener
            if (!user.uid.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                trySend(user)
            }
        }
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
        awaitClose {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
        }
    }.shareIn(
        scope = scope + "Current user",
        started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        replay = 1
    )
```